# Как включить allow_url_fopen в конфигурации PHP?

Tags: joomla, php

В конфигурации PHP joomla 1.7 параметр allow_url_fopen отключен. Для использования функций обновления необходимо включить allow_url_fopen. как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поправить умолчания php.ini через хостера. По тематике - [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804010/how-can-i-set-variable-allow-url-fopen-in-htaccess-or-php-file)